# Matrix random summary every column is 1 in java

Tags: java, random, matrix

how to create matrix 2D in java with java.util.random, when every column in this matrix get summary is 1, when i try this is still can't get summary 1 in every column,

```
for(int k=0;k<K;k++){
   for(int q=0;q<Q;q++){
        System.out.print(random.nextFloat()+" ");
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

the result is

```
0.70387095 0.3467546 0.15840572 
0.14474428 0.7011655 0.14503568 
0.8799238 0.2096222 0.7323822
```

for example column 1

```
0.70387095 + 0.3467546 + 0.8799238 != 1 but 1.93054935
```

Answer (score 4):

Compute the sum of the elements and then divide each element by that sum. This will normalize the elements so that they add up to one.

Comment: ahh, this is very clever.  Is this thought similar to turning a vector into a unit vector?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific syntax, but you could limit the random number generator to only allow number from 0 to 1 minus (sum of previous randomly generated numbers in that column)